# JPA Add extra fields by calling a function

Tags: jpa, jpql

How can I add an extra column in JPA query?
Suppose we have a table "users" created by following pseudocode:

```
create table users(name,birthdate);
```

User jpa entity is something like this :

```
@Entity
@Table("users")
public class User {

    @Basic
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Basic
    @Column
    private Date birthDate;

    @Transient
    private int age;

    //getters and setters are here
}
```

Note that the Age field is not exsists in the table
I want to write the following query in JQL using

```
entityManager.createQuery(jql)
```

and calculate age over the database

```
select u.*, sysdate-u.birthdate age from users
```

Comment: I would normally just write a method `public int getAge()`. I have no idea why you need the database to be involved here.

Comment: It's just a sample. I referred to my problem in a simplified way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is solved.**
The query text is like :

```
String jql = "select NEW entity.User(u.id, u.name, u.birthDate, sysdate-u.birthDate as age) from User u";
```

and also a appropriate constructor is added to the entity

```
public User(int id, String name, Date birthDate, double age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.age = age;
}
```

and uses entitymanaget.createQuery(jql) instead of createNativeQuery

Answer (score 0):

Usully i solve this problem using this way :

```
select new name.of.package.users(u.*, sysdate - u.birthdate as age) from users u;
```

---

**Edit**

> It leads to ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected My Query
>   text is : `String jql = "select new entity.User(u.*, sysdate-u.birthdate as age) from User u";`

The query contain an error in :

```
select new entity.User(u.*, sysdate-u.birthdate as age) from User u
//--------------------------------^^^
```

Comment: It leads to
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

My Query text is :
String jql = "select new entity.User(u.*, sysdate-u.birthdate as age) from User u";

Comment: did you create a JPQL or native query @OracleMan

Comment: I have tested both of them

Comment: @OracleMan make a space between sysdate and - and u.birthdate like this `sysdate - u.birthdate` check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using a DB-View might help. Do you want the entity to be updateable? Would it be reasonable to have a "readonly"-entity derived from a kind of "maintenance"-entity which would contain the calculated columns by using a database-view as @Table?

```
create view usersview as name, birthdate, sysdate - birthdate as age from users;
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table("usersview")
public class UserExtended extends User {
```

If you don't want two different Entity-Classes (even when one is derived from the other), there would be some exploration necessary how JPA allows updating on views, if the dbms supports it (oracle does), I have no experience in that, sorry.

Comment: Yes, It is a good idea. Oracle supports editable views, Views are editable in Oracle by default. But I am looking for better solution